# How To Set First Option As Checked In RadioButtonFor That Gets It's Data From SQL?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a RadioButtonFor that I want the default selected value to be the first option. I have a SQL table with Monday through Friday with Id, Day, and Display columns. I'm taking the Display.ToUpper() and setting that as the Value, so I can use it later in my CRON Expression. So, foreach item in Model.Days, it creates the RadioButtonItem in my RadioButtonFor, and sets the value of each as Display.Upper()..

```
@foreach (var item in Model.days)
{
    <label style="margin-right:10px;">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.subscriptions.DayOfWeek, @item.Display.ToUpper())
        @item.Display
    </label>
}
```

...I've Tried...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.subscriptions.DayOfWeek, @item.Display.ToUpper(), htmlAttributes: new { @checked = "checked" })
```

...didn't work, so I tried this in my jQuery...

```
$('input:radio[value="MON"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
or​
$('input:radio[value="MON"]').attr('checked', 'checked');​
```

...and that didn't work because blows up my KendoGrid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You set the value of the property to match the value of the input (the `RadioButtonFor()` automatically sets the correct radio button as selected if they match exactly) - We have no idea what your `DayOfWeek` property is of what `@item.Display.ToUpper()` generates

Comment: If the value of your property is `"MON"` and `@item.Display.ToUpper()` is also `"MON"` then that radio button will be selected

Comment: DayOfWeek is my string value that is coming from SQL. I have a SQL table with Monday through Friday with Id, Day, and Display columns. I'm taking the Display.ToUpper() and setting that as the Value, so I can use it later in my CRON Expression. So, foreach item in Model.Days, it creates the RadioButtonItem in my RadioButtonFor, and sets the value of each as Display.Upper().

Comment: Do they match exactly? If so then the appropriate radio button WILL be selected - that is how model binding works

Comment: Are you referring to my jQuery solution? Because they do match exactly, but it blows up my KendoGrid.

Comment: Do not use jQuery! MVC works by binding to your model, and if `@item.Display.ToUpper()` is generating `value="MON"` in your input, then the value of your `DayOfWeek` property needs to `"MON"` before you pass the model to the view if you want that radio button to be selected

Comment: So, it creates 5 Radio Buttons, M-F. How do you tell it out of the 5 days present, automatically set "MON" to be checked?

Comment: In your GET method, your set `model.subscriptions.DayOfWeek = "MON"; return View(model):` Now the radio button that has `value="MON"` will be checked.

Comment: YES! THAT WAS IT!!! Sorry for not following. I was already doing that with my active indicator. I moved on to other things, and came back to this issue, and there it is. Thank you!

                    vm.subscriptions.Active = true;
                    vm.subscriptions.DayOfWeek = "MON";

Answer (score 0):

It was just like Stephen said in the above comments...

```
AdminSubscriptionViewModel vm = new AdminSubscriptionViewModel()
{
    subscriptions = new tbl3PSubscriptions()
};
vm.subscriptions.DayOfWeek = "MON";
```